# Firebase Android custom listview

Tags: android, firebase

I'm not able to notify the change in custom `ListView` in real-time. I'm using Firebase with Java. how to notify the change in custom `ListView` when a child is removed in `onChildRemoved()`?

```java
  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      myarraylist.remove(snapshot.getValue(model.class));
      myarraylist.notifyAll();
  }
```

this method does not give me a real-time update when I back and come again to show activity then it shows update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
int index = myarraylist.getIndexOf(snapshot.getValue(model.class));

myarraylist.remove(index);
yourAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
yourAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(index, myarraylist.size());
```